# What is the number displayed next to most badges?

Tags: support, badges

I saw a gray-tinted text near most badges that says "X awarded" (where X is a number). What does it mean?

Comment: Where's this? I can't seem to find it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That number means that that number of people have been awarded/given that badge on this site because they have met the requirements needed to get the badge.